# How much time must have a web request (timeout) for a best user experience?

Tags: xml, json, sockets, http, request

How much time does a http(s) request has to have for best user experience. This is a general question for any programming language. It's the time the request takes, once the user has made an action until it's response.

Comment: Why not "The shorter the better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined time. This would heavily depend on what the application is doing at the time.  For example,  I think users are used to things such as processing financial transactions being slightly slower than typical page loads.  It really comes down to finding the right balance between the amount of content (HTML, CSS, javascript, images, etc,) and response time which leads you to what you believe is an optimal user experience.  It can also be useful to hook up analytics and specifically find out how page load times affect user behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's a usability question, not a programming question. It is usually defined by the business, or the business analysts. Ask them.